# Reference custom icon in Android code using Cordova

Tags: java, android, cordova

I'm building a Cordova app and using the excellent cordova-music-controls-plugin to create a notification card with pause/forward/etc. controls.

https://github.com/homerours/cordova-music-controls-plugin

The icon it uses looks pretty naff and if like to switch it out for the ones used on Google's material design icons site.

https://www.google.com/design/icons

I'm very confident with the JavaScript and HTML side of the app, but to make this change I need to edit some Android (I assume Java) code.

Can anybody help by letting me know:
- where I need to import the icon files
- how I reference then in the plugin code

```
/* Pause*/
nbControls++;

Intent pauseIntent = new Intent("music-controls-pause");

PendingIntent pausePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1, pauseIntent, 0);
            builder.addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause, "", pausePendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You only have to fork the plugin, and replace the icon for the one that you want, keeping the file format, size and name

Comment: As far as I can see, the plugin doesn't include any icon files - instead it's referencing a default Android system drawable. [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.drawable.html)